# JS causing infinite loop in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache-flex, firefox

A script on my page is causing an infinite loop in FireFox.

Here is the Javascript:

```
function expandMothersRings(new_height)
{
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    $('#mr-container').animate({
        height: new_height
    }, 100, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
}
```

This is being called via `ExternalInterface` from a Flex object:

```
var tiles_height:Number = 175+Math.ceil(MothersRingData.getInstance().styleArrayCollection.length/4)*175;
ExternalInterface.call("expandMothersRings", tiles_height + 300);
```

There is no issue in IE or Chrome. But for some reason the `expandMothersRings` function is infinitely looping in FF.

The flex object is not expecting any return value from Javascript. Also if I change the JS function to look like:

```
function expandMothersRings(new_height)
{
    alert(new_height);
}
```

Then it only executes once. So something in the function is causing it to loop in Firefox.

I do not know what?

Here is [the page](http://www.kranichs.com/mothers-rings)

Comment: The page keeps trying to reload for me in FF.. could that be what's causing your problem?

Comment: Do you have any code in "Animation complete" method?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, no I did not, I was thinking I might add some so I was leaving it commented like that while debuging, but didn't need to. Turns out I didn't really need it to animate either, as you can see I had it set to 100ms. I changed it not to animate at all just set it, that fixed the issue.

Comment: @John that's weird.. used jQuery animation before without any problems..

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, yeah, I am sure it was probably the combination of that with something else unknown interfering.

Comment: @John - indeed, I would guess it's Flex but don't have any proof of course. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced

```
$('#mr-container').animate({
    height: new_height
}, 100, function() {
    // Animation complete.
});
```

with

```
$("#mr-container").height(new_height);
```

That fixed the issue.